# Error after update Android Studio 1.5 Package name is no valid

Tags: android, updates

After I updated Android Studio to version 1.5 and updated the SDK, now in all my projects I can not add new activities. It gives me an error (see picture).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you at least one time google it? how to create package name in android studio?

Comment: Please consider posting your image directly on stackoverflow. The link might get corrupted in the future.

Comment: what? i know about the reglas for public in GooglePlay, but i do not want public in GooglePlay yet, so they change the reglas in Android Studio and all your proyects are invalid? , i do not agree